# gpg error: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed

Tags: gnupg

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I am unable to run any gpg commands without using sudo. I can't generate keys, I can't list keys etc. The error message I get is:
*gpg: starting migration from earlier GnuPG versions
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: error: GnuPG agent unusable. Please check that a GnuPG agent can be started.
gpg: migration aborted*

The odd thing is that these commands succeed if I use sudo. However I need to use gpg with the pass utility and when I try to do this, pass gives the error message "Encryption failed: no public key". I suspect this is because if I generate keys using sudo they will only be accessible to the  root user.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling gpg but I still get the same error.
I have also tried using gpg1 but I don't think pass is accepting gpg1 keys. Someone please tell me what I'm missing here. Thanks.

Comment: I solved it guys. The problem was a corrupt gpg-agent.conf file. I don't why it didn't get deleted when I uninstalled and reinstalled.